# Android emulator shows "black screen"

Tags: android-studio

The app runs on a real device (Hello World). Let the App run on the Android virtual machine, the Android window says the App is running on the Emulator, but the AVD virtual machine shows a black screen??? If anyone knows what to do, please help me. I've been struggling for a week now...Thank you

I have tried to install many Android Studio, the latest version is ok (But its interface is not the same as the teacher's version. I am taking an Android class - I can't learn), installing the old version has errors, . ..I installed it today (AroticFox 2020.3.1 version (released July 28, 2021)), I can continue studying. I don't have a real device yet (I borrowed it to try the App), so I want to use an Android virtual device. I hope everyone can help me how to make the virtual machine run well. Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg0Dz.png)